# Why is length scaling equivalent to series transistors?

Tags: mosfet, vlsi, solid-state-devices

In what follows, I am neglecting all non-idealities. All transistors are assumed to obey the first-order, long-channel IV characteristics.

My VLSI text (Weste and Harris) claims that, given these assumptions, the two circuits below draw the same currents for every value of \$V_{ds}\$, but I can't see why this should be. I have verified the claim if \$V_{ds}\$ is such that all transistors are in the triode region, or if all transistors are in saturation. But what about the intermediate regime, wherein the transistor in (a) goes into saturation but it is not the case (at least a priori) that both of the transistors in (b) are in saturation? Is there a way to show that if (a) is in saturation then both transistors in (b) are in saturation perhaps?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The right sketch is basically identical to the left one. It merely creates a virtual divide half way along the channel in order to represent it as two transistor with common gate.

Now why is the current equivalent?

In any such transistor, the drain voltage will be higher than the source voltage. Therefore, the voltage in the channel will decrease gradually as you think your way through it from drain to source.

This in turn means that the gate-to-channel voltage will be largest near the source and smallest at the drain. The channel resistance is largest near the drain. The drain provides the choke point for current to go through when the FET is saturated.

This means that the bottom transistor in the two-FET-model will be always in the ohmic region, because current is limited by the (topmost end of the) top FET. This *is* the normal saturated operation. There is no operation region where both transistors would be saturated.

Comment: I think this is the crux, so thank you for pointing it out: "There is no operation region where both transistors would be saturated." Would it be possible to supply a mathematical argument to that effect using the typical square-law/long-channel model of a transistor?